# Executing SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I have just started learning about SSIS package, so plz bear if answer of my query seems obvious to you :-)

I have an SSIS package that need to be installed in different environments as DEV/SYSTEST/DTE/LIVE. Please note that SQL Server connection string is different in each environment - so need different config files.

The way I am thinking to deploy this is

- Create separate package configuration file for different environments
- Create an environment variable say 'MyPackageConfigPath' to hold the
  path of config file.
- Run the package using DtExec command with /ConfigFile switch

My questions:

- Is this a good way of deploying SSIS package in different
  environments?
- Any other better way of executing package in this scenario?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2005-2008 R2 or 2012 with Package Deployment Model, your options for configuration are

1. Parent Package
2. Registry value
3. Environment variable
4. Command line assignment
5. XML file
6. Database table

You can generally group them into single-value configuration (1-4) and multi-value configuration (5-6). There are pros and cons for all of them but I find I have the best experience with a database table as my primary configuration repository. All my values are stored in there for a given environment so each environment (dev, test, load, stage, prod) server would have a dedicated catalog with a table for configuration (as well as logging and other ETL specific things)

### Table approach

If you don't like my table, you can create your own or let BIDS/SSDT do it.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SSISConfig
(
    id identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,   ConfigurationFilter nvarchar(150) NOT NULL -- Package Name
,   ConfiguredValue nvarchar(255) NULL -- Value of setting, such as a connection string
,   PackagePath nvarchar(255) NOT NULL -- Target within SSIS package where value is written
,   ConfiguredValueType nvarchar(20) NOT NULL -- Data type such as String, Int32, or DateTime
)
```

And an example on the DEV server would look like

```
id  | ConfigurationFilter| ConfiguredValue                                                                         | PackagePath                                              | ConfiguredValueType
100 | Default.2005.Sales | Data Source=DEV;Initial Catalog=SALESDEVDB;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI; | \Package.Connections[SLSDB].Properties[ConnectionString] | String
```

That same row in production would look like

```
id  | ConfigurationFilter| ConfiguredValue                                                                          | PackagePath                                              | ConfiguredValueType
123 | Default.2005.Sales | Data Source=PROD;Initial Catalog=SALESPRODB;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI; | \Package.Connections[SLSDB].Properties[ConnectionString] | String
```

We have configuration deployment scripts that factor in the server being deployed to to handle the database and server name changes so there is only one script to maintain. I find XML files are harder to keep in sync for cases like that (crap, we forgot to update production's config file and we pulled in the wrong data).

### The trick

The trick to making this work, as you have identified in your second bullet, is that you need some mechanism of telling SSIS to use a different set of configurations. If you do not have multi-instanced machines, then I find using an environment variable to be an excellent approach. Define it once per server that executes packages and you are done. If you work in a multi-instanced environment, then it becomes a trickier situation.

I though HLGEM had a rather clever approach in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157180/dynamically-changing-server-names-in-ssis) of using different service accounts with local environment variables in multi-instanced environments. You can scroll down to see my approach on multi-instanced machines.

Assorted answers where I covered configuration

- [Dynamically Changing Server Names in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157180/dynamically-changing-server-names-in-ssis/11158890#11158890)
- [Executing the same SSIS Package with different parameters at different time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384850/executing-the-same-ssis-package-with-different-parameters-at-different-time/8386338#8386338)
- [Overridding SSIS Environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822347/overridding-ssis-environment-variable/10822625#10822625)
- [How to modify the variable in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064438/how-to-modify-the-variable-in-ssis/9066670#9066670)
- [How to execute dtsx packages through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787007/how-to-execute-dtsx-packages-through-command-line/8790987#8790987)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is the one that works for your situation. Not incredibly helpful but, there you have it. I can't see why your solution wouldn't work.

Some places are a bit picky about adding environment variables on production machines. If you're able to do that, no problems. If not, would you be able to have the config file in the same place on each machine and hard code the location? Plus that's one less thing to worry about when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like fiddling with environment variables and I find it easier to use an "SQL Server" config element in the package configuration. It creates a configuration table of predefined structure in a database of your choice. That database might even be "config123" on server "localhost". That's what I do. I then keep that config database on both my local development machine and the server, but with different values for the config entries.
This means the package uses my local config settings when I develop and automagically uses the production server config when run by the server. :-)

We also keep packages in msdb (DeploymentManifests are created by Visual Studio, no biggie) and let the SQL Server Agent run those packages periodically. That makes it really easy to deploy changes. Just deploy the updated package into msdb and you're good to go.